# Does the regex (?<char>\s\w+)\k<char> match the text "the theory"?

Tags: .net, regex, pattern-matching

The book I'm reading says it does. I think it doesn't because it the word "the" doesn't have a space in front of it.

What say you?

Comment: Thanks vcsjones, looks like I am right. Stupid book!

Comment: Correct. A regex that does match is `(?<char>\w+)\s\k<char>` I assume the point of the book was to say "a word that matches the beginning of the next word", like `pin pinboard`

Comment: No it was actually showing the different text that would match that regex, and it just forgot a space! The other examples all started with a space.

Comment: Ah, well, that doesn't work either :-). You could check the publisher's site of the book to see if they published any corrections. Lots of tech books do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It's not an exact match, but it will capture `theory (space theory)`.

Comment: ok, now I understand, the text you were referring to was "theory (space theory)", but the formatting was off. I fixed it.